# How to write independent THEN phrases in user story scenarios

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm trying to write a scenario :

```
As a user
......
Scenario: Breaking a rule
Given:I'm an active user
When: I break the rule 'X'
Then: I should be added to rule breakers' list
```

But`rule breakers' list` is defined in another story.
So this story is no more independent.

We can change the `Then` phrase to this:

```
Then: The rule 'X' should be breaked by me
```

But the behavior of my scenario doesn't seem clear enough.

More examples:

```
Scenario: Registration
.....
Then: I should be loged in
```

(While login belongs to another scenario)vs

```
Then: I should be registered
```

And the real problem comes to the action when navigation is something your stakeholders care about.

**My question:**
    How can I have an independent scenarios which are clearer in situations like that?

Answer (score 1):

If the rule breaker's list is defined elsewhere, it's part of the state in which the scenario starts, so it's a "given".

Your scenario should resemble something like:

```
As a user
......
Scenario: Breaking a rule
Given:I'm an active user
And:  I'm not in the rule breakers' list <- Add another given
When: I break the rule 'X'
Then: I should be added to rule breakers' list
```

The extra "given" can reuse the same code as the other scenario, if that's useful. Alternatively, you can use a shortcut, like putting data directly into the database rather than going through the UI. It's fine for this scenario to have no knowledge of how that list comes into being, as long as there's an example of that somewhere else.

Comment: But referring to another scenaroi breaks independence rule defined here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic) , doesn't it?

Comment: Even if I put the data directly into database , I'm implementing the database layer of another story that may or may not implemented yet.It's not gonna be independent as well.

Comment: @Mohsen You're not referring to another scenario. You're just re-using the same code, and that's perfectly fine. And, maybe you just need a database that can be manually edited? Why not? Why does there need to be another story? What's the smallest thing you can deliver that works?

Comment: Maybe that works for some scenarios ,but say that the the `rule breakers' list` has some filterable fields to give the ability of finding the cause of breaking rules in a certain situation.Or , there are other stories that may need to include phrases about  the `rule breakers  list`.(Of course the `rule breakers' list` is just a sample here;if I merge all of the stories I mentioned then the resulting story is no more small, and makes the estimation and size balancing hard.

Comment: If you need the rule breaker's list to have filterable fields, illustrate that behaviour using another scenario. Also INVEST is about backlog items, not scenarios. A scenario is an *example* of behaviour, not a backlog item. For example, filtering a list of rule-breakers is independent to adding people to a list of rule-breakers; you can do the first with a manually-created list, and the second is independent of the filter.

Comment: :That's right but if you place such scenarios in a single story , that story (probably) bloats over time ,and the size of that kind of story is (probably) isn't under control. I was actually looking for a certain solution to all problems like that; So that many stories could be written for many developers who don't even know about other stories (and each other).

Comment: Don't place them in a single story, then. I tend to group scenarios by capability, then by high-level context if the capability is large. It's also OK (and pretty much essential) to refactor your scenarios over time and change how they're stored as your codebase grows - you don't want them scattered to start with, but you'll want them grouped more sensibly later on, so separate things out when that happens. Change is constant. Make it so it's easy to change and you'll be fine. Also, give it a go instead of guessing as to what's going to go wrong; learn by doing.

Answer (score 0):

What is a "user story scenario"? User stories come and go they are not much more than a piece of paper and some discussion. After the user story is finished, it has unsignificant relevance. However, your gherkins are there to stay as automated tests and living documentation. After the user story is finished, you can deliver a new function. What is that function? Your gherkin should describe exactly that and nothing more.

In your example: ok, there might be some plans that we are also going to keep a list of rule-breakers, but let's concentrate first on the immediate user story and forget about such a list. That list might be a separate user story later on or it may never even happen. So the question is: what immediate value has my current user story, what is the functionality that the users will see. If it's just some feedback to the user along some rules, than that is what my gherkins should reflect: Given some preconditions When I'm breaking rule 'X' Than I should receive feedback this or that way.

If it is difficult to come up with sensible gherkin scenarios, chances are high that you have split up your user stories inappropriately (which BTW is not a problem, but something best found out as early as possible - which is the very reason you are using bdd.)